# Amazon S3 VPC endpoint access issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

Do we need to make the S3 bucket public? if we want to use a VPC endpoint to access the bucket. The bucket is private and I have a bucket policy as follows.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1415115909152",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-XXXXXXXXX"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I am getting the following error while accessing it

```
403 Forbidden
Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied
RequestId: 3B5263AFE5F08F7D
HostId: M2+BaRG/GqiasUSkPo9rC46aC84pmZHNcbSnA2UcWcHxWntFRWjcli7VdN0wLpnsSZgK659008Y=
```

I have enabled static website hosting on the bucket, Idea was to access it privately in the VPC.

Comment: How are you accessing S3? Is it via a URL, or an API call? Also, have you configured the Route table on the subnet to point to the VPC Endpoint for S3?

Comment: Accessing S3 via URL. Didn't make any changes to the route tables. I would like to access via a URL in the browser from within the office network. Office network is peered with the VPC where the VPC endpoint is created.

Comment: So, is this your flow? `Computer in office -> VPN or Direct Connect -> VPC A -> VPC Peering -> VPC B -> VPC Endpoint for S3`? I doubt that this is possible because you would need a Route Table on VPC A that directs to the VPC Endpoint in VPC B. However, other people might be able to comment.